# What is tomcat.bin?

Tags: apache, tomcat

Ok, this is a daft question but there is no straight out of the box answer on Google as far as I can tell.

I see some of our servers have it, some don't.

So I know it's related to Apache/Tomcat etc.. but what does it do ?

is it bin as in binary or bin as in trash bin, like it's generated by the Garbage Collector ?

Thanks!

Comment: In which locations do you find this file?

Comment: /app/tomcat-dumps